# ArrayStoreException while assigning default value using Arrays.fill method in java

Tags: java

trying to assign default value using Arrays.fill method, but I'm getting ArrayStoreException. Code is given Below "for finding all path from source to destination in 2d array with only k moves"

I went through few links(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120089/convert-arraylist-to-array-throws-java-lang-arraystoreexception,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369957/dealing-with-an-arraystoreexception), but not able to locate the problem

```
public class FindPathWithConstaint {
    int[][][][] dp = new int[100][100][100][2];
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int m = 3, n = 3, k =2;
        FindPathWithConstaint obj = new FindPathWithConstaint();
        System.out.println(obj.findAllPath(m,n,k));     
    }

    public int findAllPath(int m, int n, int k) {       
        if(m==0 && n==0)
            return 1;
        Arrays.fill(dp,-1);
        return countAllPaths(m-1,n,k,1) + countAllPaths(m,n-1,k,0);     
    }

    public int countAllPaths(int i, int j, int k, int d) {
        if(i<0 || j<0)
            return 0;
        if(i==0 && j==0)
            return 1;
        if(k==0) {
            if(d==0 && i==0)
                return 1;
            if(d==1 && j==0)
                return 1;
        }
        if(dp[i][j][k][d]!=-1)
             return dp[i][j][k][d];
        if(d==0)
            return countAllPaths(i,j-1,k,0) + countAllPaths(i-1,j,k-1,1);
        else
            return countAllPaths(i-1,j,k,1) + countAllPaths(i,j-1,k-1,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Having this error because you have declared dp as Multidimentional array in this line

```
int[][][][] dp = new int[100][100][100][2];
```

Which mean that you gonna have an array of arrays, then you have tried to assigne values to this array using `Arrays.fill()` which throws error in this line

```
Arrays.fill(dp,-1);
```

it throws an exception because the `fill` method try to affect an integer "-1" to each element of dp array, although dp is an array of arrays not an array of integers and that is exactly the cause of the exception,

Comment: thanks for noticing the cause, problem solved